# PHP Oracle Insert oci_bind_by_name from query results

Tags: php, oracle, bind

There are two Oracle databases and I would like to copy some of the data from one and put it in the other. I can't seem to figure out how to use the oci_bind_by_name or oci_bind_array_by_name using the results from the first SQL query. I get inserts in the 2nd database, but all of the fields are NULL.

```
<?php
$conn = oci_connect('o_database', 'o_db1_pass', 'localhost/db1');

$conn2 = oci_connect('o_database2', 'o_db2_pass', 'localhost/db2');

$query = "SELECT row_id, animal_type, name, weight FROM db1.animals";
$stid = oci_parse($conn, $query);
oci_execute($stid);

$sql = "INSERT INTO db2.data_animals 
                    (ROW_ID, ANIMAL_TYPE, NAME, WEIGHT)
            VALUES (:ROW_ID, :ANIMAL_TYPE, :NAME, :WEIGHT)";

$stid3 = oci_parse($conn2, $sql);
 
oci_bind_by_name($stid3, ":ROW_ID", $row['ROW_ID'], -1, SQLT_CHR); 
oci_bind_by_name($stid3, ":ANIMAL_TYPE", $row['ANIMAL_TYPE'], -1, SQLT_CHR); 
oci_bind_by_name($stid3, ":NAME", $row['NAME'], -1, SQLT_CHR); 
oci_bind_by_name($stid3, ":WEIGHT", $row['WEIGHT'], -1, SQLT_INT); 
 
while (($row = oci_fetch_array ($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) != false) { 
    // Fetch NULLs
    print_r($row);
    oci_execute($stid3);
}

oci_close($conn);
oci_close($conn2);

 
?>
```

Comment: Binding requires the data at a memory address to be unchanged. But fetching each row creates a different location.  Try putting the bind calls inside the loop.

Comment: Tried that and still nothing.

Comment: You were correct Christopher Jones, had to move the bind into the WHILE statement.  It didn't work the first time had made other changes that were failing.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  You can tune [prefetching](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-set-prefetch.php) to help improve fetch performance.  PHP OCI8 doesn't have an "execute many" capability, so if speed is important but the language isn't important, look at using Python cx_Oracle, see [Batch Statement Execution and Bulk Loading](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html). This driver has an `executemany()` call that helps improve INSERT performance.